# Adding Redemption assembly to PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, outlook, outlook-redemption

I recently posted a question about a problem I was having with my powershell script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553772/using-outlook-propertyaccessor-in-powershell).
The helpful people here guided me to the solution which was using Redemption library.

After looking in to what Redemption is, and what it can do, I decided to give it a go and install the files. Now I'm facing the problem where I can't quite ComObjects of Redemption.

### My Code:

```
$routlook = New-Object -COM Redemption.RDOSession
$routlook.Logon

$junk = $routlook.GetDefaultFolder($OlFolderJunk)
$MI = $box.items

$MI|select  SenderName, SenderEmailAddress, To, Subject, Body
```

The goal is to just simply show the fields listed above in a table. I want to see the sender's name, the sender's e-mail address, the recipient, the subject and the content (or body)

### The Return Value (The Error)

[image]

I'm assuming this has something to do with the the missing assembly reference? If so please explain how I add this library to the assembly, cause I'm quite new to Powershell scripting.

Thank you.

Comment: did you tried to run it on powershell x32 bit?

Comment: Wow now I'm pretty ashamed. I didn't think about that. It works, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to load it in PowerShell x32 Bit, or get the x64 Bit dll version

Comment: I have the x64 bit dll version but it's still only working on 32bit version. Shouldn't it be working on both now then?

Answer (score 1):

This error is an indication that bitness of your code is different from the bitness of the MAPI system (Outlook). See http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#ErrorCreatingRedemptionObject